# App process does not die when stopping a bound foreground service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, foreground-service

I have a bound foreground service that is supposed to live even when the app is removed from recents, but with the option to also stop the service when the app gets removed. That optional path is what I am having trouble with.

If the service is not set as foreground, stopping the service causes the process to die as well. This is the desired effect:

[image]

However, if the service is set as foreground, the app process does not die:

[image]

What I tried:

1. Stopping from `onTaskRemoved` inside the service:

```kotlin
    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent) {
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }
```

2. Setting `stopAppWithTask` to true in the manifest:

```xml
   <service
        android:name=".TestService" android:stopWithTask="true">
   </service>
```

3. Stopping via activity:

```kotlin
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    unbindService(connection)
  
    mBound = false
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Intent(applicationContext, TestService::class.java).also { intent ->
        stopService(intent)
    }
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

4. Same as .3, but I stop the service as foreground in `onStop`. This works, but it's not ideal, as the service will stop being foreground every time the app is put to recents.

```kotlin
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mService.stopForeground()
        unbindService(connection)
        mBound = false
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Intent(applicationContext, TestService::class.java).also { intent ->
            stopService(intent)
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

```kotlin
    // in the service
    fun stopForeground() {
        stopForeground(true)
    }
```

The questions I have are the following:

1. Is the app process not stopping the desired effect?
2. If yes, why does the process never die? I would be fine with the OS eventually killing the service, but it never happens (from what I have noticed)
3. Why does stopping foreground in `onStop` lead to the process dying properly, but stopping it in `onTaskRemoved` keeps the process alive.

Comment: "If the service is not set as foreground, stopping the service causes the process to die as well" -- not necessarily. When processes are terminated is up to the OS and will vary by OS version and device model (based on manufacturer changes to the OS).

Comment: "with the option to also stop the service" -- What initiates the service to be stopped? Does the user press a 'stop' button in the foreground service notification? "if the service is set as foreground, the app process does not die" -- Foreground Services specifically indicate to the OS that its process should not be killed; so this is intended behavior. Additionally, as CommonsWare commented, the OS determines when the process is killed; the OS may keep your process around in case the user navigates back to your app

Answer (score 0):

1. If a service is started by the literal act of a client binding to it, that service will stop as soon as all clients are unbound. Note that it will only stop once all clients are unbound.

   So if 5 clients bind to the service, then 5 clients unbind from the
   service, the service will be destroyed.
2. If a service is started using either the startService method or the startForegroundService method, then a client binds to it, the service will continue running until the stopSelf method is called. The act of unbinding has no effect on whether the service stays alive or not since it was started before any clients were bound.

Comment: I am aware of both of these cases. In my example I use 2. to start and stop the service manually, but the app process still remains alive.